# NET Mvc add to list a different instances objects from another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've started to learn .NET mvc and I've been struggling with this for a while.
The below code was simplified just to show the problem.

I have a model with a class like this, which includes a list of dogs:

```
public class Animals {

   public long id {get; set;}

   public List<Dog> Dogs {get; set;}
}
```

I have another model called Dog, with instances of each breed, which I constructed like this:

```
public class Dog
{
   public Puddle Puddle {get; set;}

   public Retriver Retriver {get; set;}

   public Terrier Terrier {get; set;}
}

public class Puddle {

   public string Name {get; set;}
   
   public DateTime DayOfBirth {get; set;}

}

public class Retriver {

   public string Name {get; set;}

   public int Age {get; set;}
}

public class Terrier {

   public string color {get; set;}

}
```

My aim is to create a list of dogs under the Animal object. In other words, add a dog object to a list, depending on what breed a user will choose in the view.
My controller:

```
public ActionResult AddDog(long id, string breed, DateTime date)
        {
            var animal = db.Animals.Find(id);
            if (animal == null) return HttpNotFound();

            if (breed == "puddle")
            {
                Dog<Puddle> newPuddle = new Dog<Puddle>()
                {
                    DayOfBirth = date
                };
                animal.Dogs.Add(newPuddle );
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Each breed will have a different properties. I want a single list of different type of dogs under Animal object.
In the above controller, of course I cannot use Puddle as a type argument, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. Please don't be harsh with me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really make sense. Why does a `Dog` have three other dogs as properties?

Are you trying to create a `Dog` "superclass" that can be inherited to provide more specific types of dogs? If so, then `Puddle` (should that be `Poodle`?) would not be standalone classes, but would inherit from `Dog`. For example...

```cs
public class Dog {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Terrier : Dog {
  public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

`Terrier` will now have the properties from `Dog`, such as `Id` and `Name`, as well as the terrier-specific `Color`.

If that's not what you're trying to do, then please clarify your question.